# Constructing ElasticSearch Query with nested Should operator

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I am struggling to create a simple ElasticSearch Query.
This is what i want to achieve in simple SQL

`SELECT * FROM products WHERE (title='LG' OR title='Nokia') AND (brand='Samsung' OR title='iPhone')`

This is my Elasticsearch query:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "product-name": "Samsung"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "product-name": "Nokia"
                }
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1

          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

This returns me the first line of the Psuedo SQL `WHERE (title='LG' OR title='Nokia')`

But how can i construct the `AND (brand='Samsung' OR title='iPhone')`

Answer (score 2):

Following query should get the job done. You need to add one more block in `must`  clause.

```
{
  "query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
              "product-name": "LG"
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "product-name": "Nokia"
            }
          }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1

      }
    } ,
     {
      "bool": {
        "should": [
          {
            "match": {
              "brand": "Samsung"
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "title": "iPhone"
            }
          }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1

         }
       }
     ]
   }
  }    
}
```

Hope this helps